# How to run newer app version on unsupported iOS versions?

Tags: ios, ios6, ios7, ipod-touch, ios6.1

I like the redesigned version of Evernote and want to install it on my iPod touch 4th gen. with iOS 6.1.3. I opened up its `plist` file, looked for any parameter that would relate to iOS version restriction but I couldn't find any.

Does anyone know where/how I can edit the source code so I can use it on my iPod touch?

Comment: Can you find MinimumOSVerion key in the info.plist file?

Comment: I don't believe newer versions of apps are alalowed on previous iOS versions. If you do not have the option to update Evernote on your iPod, you are stuck to using the last update for iOS 6

Comment: Evernote is not an open source project -- the code is not available for you to edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just edit the minimum OS version and expect it to work. There are several problems with that.

1. The app bundle is read-only, and code-signed. Any changes to it and it won't run. You could probably solve #1 on a jailbroken phone.
2. App developers tend to use OS features and APIs from the minimum OS version without any runtime testing that those features are available, because the system is supposed to prevent the app from running on earlier OS versions. If you defeat the minimum OS check and the developer uses a class or method that is not in the older OS, the app will crash.